# How to put attributes via XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this code:

```
XElement EcnAdminConf = new XElement("Type",
    new XElement("Connections",
    new XElement("Conn"),
    // Conn.SetAttributeValue("Server", comboBox1.Text);
    // Conn.SetAttributeValue("DataBase", comboBox2.Text))),
    new XElement("UDLFiles")));
    // Conn.
```

How do I add attributes to `Conn`? I want to add the attributes I marked as comments, but if I try to set the attributes on `Conn` after defining `EcnAdminConf`, they are not visible.

I want to set them somehow so the XML looks like this:

```
<Type>
  <Connections>
    <Conn ServerName="FAXSERVER\SQLEXPRESS" DataBase="SPM_483000" /> 
    <Conn ServerName="FAXSERVER\SQLEXPRESS" DataBase="SPM_483000" /> 
  </Connections>
  <UDLFiles /> 
</Type>
```

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Add `XAttribute` in the constructor of the `XElement`, like

```
new XElement("Conn", new XAttribute("Server", comboBox1.Text));
```

You can also add multiple attributes or elements via the constructor

```
new XElement("Conn", new XAttribute("Server", comboBox1.Text), new XAttribute("Database", combobox2.Text));
```

or you can use the Add-Method of the `XElement` to add attributes

```
XElement element = new XElement("Conn");
XAttribute attribute = new XAttribute("Server", comboBox1.Text);
element.Add(attribute);
```

Comment: Is it possible to build a list or array of xAttr and add them all at once?

Comment: @greg you could use the .Add()-overload to pass in multiple XAttribute objects (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Add_System_Object___)