# Xml-C# i can't set a value for the element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
XElement service = doc.Element("Ids");
service.Add(new XElement("ID", idulong.ToString(),new XElement("Succesfull",1)));
```

Example output

```
<ID>
9223372036854775808
<Succesfull>1</Succesfull>
</ID>`
```

I want

```
<Ids Userid= 9223372036854775808>  
<Succesfull>1</Succesfull>
</Ids>
```

The Id is different for each user.I want check users with id.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code *just* changed to show the level of nesting:

```
service.Add(new XElement("ID",
                         idulong.ToString(),
                         new XElement("Succesfull",
                                      1)));
```

In other words, the `Succesfull` element is within the `ID` element constructor call.

You just want to add two separate elements, either with two separate calls to `service.Add`:

```
service.Add(new XElement("ID", idulong.ToString());
service.Add(new XElement("Succesfull", 1));
```

or in one call to `Add`, taking multiple elements:

```
service.Add(new XElement("ID", idulong.ToString()),
            new XElement("Succesfull", 1));
```

You don't need to call `ToString`, by the way - it's fine to write:

```
service.Add(new XElement("ID", idulong),
            new XElement("Succesfull", 1));
```

(You might want to use `Successful` or just `Success` instead of `Succesfull` though...)

Comment: Thx for your answer but this doesn't work because i try a create user.This codes create different elements i want create element(for each user) and apply elements.This is my bad i didn't create a true question

Comment: @user4126354: Sorry, I don't understand your comment at all. This will create the XML you said you wanted. If that's not *actually* what you want, you should be clearer in your question. What do you mean by "apply elements"?

Comment: Oh thx for the all answers.i want check user with id element afaik i'm need aply attribute for the id. Is this true?

Comment: @user4126354: I have no idea what you mean by that. *Please* take the time to actually clarify what you mean.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I strongly suspect that invalid XML `<Ids Userid= 9223372036854775808>` shown in the question meant to demonstrate "how to create an element with UserId attribute" (which look like already answered some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063936/how-to-put-attributes-via-xelement)... Not really sure why `Ids` element would have `UserId` attribute so...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Ah - that's very different from the original question. The OP has edited the question, but not actually mentioned it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XElement service = doc.Element("Ids");
service.Add(
    new XElement("ID", idulong.ToString()),
    new XElement("Succesfull", 1)
);
```

Comment: thx but this create different elements same to my code

Comment: @user4126354: When you get three answers, none of which you like, all of which do exactly what you actually *asked* for, you should think about whether you asked clearly enough...

Comment: Exactly @JonSkeet.......

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement service = doc.Element("Ids");
service.Add(new XElement("ID", idulong.ToString()),
        new XElement("Succesfull", 1));
```

not

```
service.Add(new XElement("ID", idulong.ToString(),new XElement("Succesfull",1)));
```

Comment: this code create different element on Ids