# How to build specific XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading and building a new xml string in C# like this:

```
private string XmlString
{
    get
    {
        if (my_xml.Nodes().Count() > 0)
        {
            var param = new XElement("param");

            var ids = my_xml.Elements("ID").ToList();
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                param.Add(new XElement("ids", new XElement("ID", id.Value)));
            }
            return param.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get a xml string which is something like:

```
<param>
    <ids>
        <id>2</id>
    </ids>
</param>
```

How should look like my method to get a xml string like this one with = :

```
  <param>
        <ids id="2"/>
  </param>
```

Comment: What if `my_xml` as more than one ID element?  Where do you expect to set all the id attributes?  Should there be more than one `ids` element in that case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put attributes via XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063936/how-to-put-attributes-via-xelement)

Comment: @juharr I put Anu Viswan's answer in a foreach loop. It is working with many id's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SetAttributeValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue?view=netframework-4.8) for adding an attribute.

```
var xElement = new XElement("ids"); 
xElement.SetAttributeValue("id",id.Value);
param.Add(xElement);
```

Alternatively, you could also use an override of `XElement` Constructor

```
param.Add(new XElement("ids", new XAttribute("id", id.Value)));
```

Comment: That's it!  I see you added `.Value` too. Thanks!